# Can I feed my goldfish my red cherry shrimp?

Tags: fish, safety, feeding, goldfish, live-food

I have many low grade cherry shrimps. Can I feed them to my goldfish?

Low grade is instead of bright red, the color is fade red or transparent.

Comment: Could you please clarify in what sense are these shrimp "low grade"? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Goldfish are very hungry creatures. They will happily eat your low grade red cherry shrimp. When I was younger, and had no experience of keeping goldfish, my family put 10 beautiful Amano shrimp into a goldfish tank not knowing that goldfish would chow down on shrimp.  The next day most of them were eaten. Shrimp are edible for goldfish, as evidenced by the result of this mistake.

Comment: How do feed the goldfish with shrimps? Just put it on the 95 g tank I don't know if the goldfish will ever find it

Comment: If you allow the shrimps to enter your tank, even with cover; such as plants and rocks, they will soon be eaten in a few days.